# Number of samples for final render in Cycles

Tags: rendering

[image]

I am rendering with GPU and sample rate is 300 [no ambient occlusion] But i am getting too noise and fog type things here in this image you can see. can you please tell me the best rendering settings for this types of render. also a tutorial about to nice studio light setup.

Comment: You need a lot more than 300 samples usually - try 2000. This will obviously take much longer to render, so you need to balance an acceptable render time with an acceptable noise level. Also, the "fog" you're seeing looks like just a reflection of the white wall, make your material less reflective by reducing the amount of glossy shader you're mixing in.

Comment: Check "square samples" in the "Samples" panel. This will render Samples^2 points, so a sample of 24 is the same number of sampleas as 576 "normal" samples.